# Stage environment for Magento for dummies - 500 internal server error

Tags: magento, stage

I'm brand new to server side setup and creating staging environments. I have a magento live environment I've setup, but now I want to setup a stage environment (stage.mystore.com) and practice rolling from stage to live. But, I'm a newb to this and having issues.

I started by following this tutorial to the T, but am currently stuck:

http://www.crucialwebhost.com/kb/setting-up-a-magento-staging-area/

I can load my homepage on the stage subdomain, but any link I click on gives me an "500 internal server error". Secure and unsecure.

I've read around a lot, and it seems like I probably need to either edit something else in my .htaccess or core_config_data but I'm uncertain what to do next.

Can anyone provide more complete step by step instructions for this last part for me?

Comment: Have you tried checking logs like exception log for magento and also for apache error logs.that will help you out to trace exact problem

Comment: This might help point you in the right direction.  Check your `RewriteBase` declaration in your .htaccess file: http://www.magentocommerce.com/boards/viewthread/290044/

Comment: PhilB, that helped thank you. One more thing, I could not login to admin. I've tried the solutions listed here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2176195/cant-log-in-to-magento-admin, and editing the varien.php file worked, after also clearing out my browser cookies.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PhilB's response worked. I just needed to do that change to the varien.php file AND clear out all cookies from my live server in my browser and then I could login. thanks.