# after installing magento cannot login admin

Tags: magento

After installing **Magento** `admin panel` cannot log in. I have installed magento on my localhost. After all the setup when I used the admin page to login I can't able to login in chrome browser even with my right username and password

Comment: Please visit this site

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2176195/cant-log-in-to-magento-admin

it may help you

Comment: **Thanks** problem has been slove.

Comment: Hi, plus one for the interesting question, I'm just wondering, did the workaround of using a different browser work for you?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about website administration.

Answer (score 4):

I found this solution : Go to app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Session/Abstract/Varien.php file within your magento directory and comment out these 3 lines of code :
Also the comma must be removed from the file .Save it and try to login to your magento admin panel.

```
// 'domain'   => $cookie->getConfigDomain(),
// 'secure'   => $cookie->isSecure(),
// 'httponly' => $cookie->getHttponly()
```

Comment: More info is in magento's wiki http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/how_to_fix_login_for_admin_on_local_install

Comment: This works for me but why we have to change this file?

Comment: Can't find the sub folders in the app folder, please help me

Comment: It's a bad idea to hack core files

Answer (score 0):

first check your local server (like wamp, xammp etc) is working correct
second chack your appache configaration port is 80 .... and 
third goto magento directory and see if manifast.flag file in that directory delete it ...

Answer (score 0):

Try it in Firefox , I have faced the same issue but when i tried in Firefox i logged in successfully.

Answer (score -1):

it happens to me after installing everytime,
find this file:
app\code\core\Mage\Core\Model\Session\Abstract\Varien.php

And commenting out the following (it's lines 85 to 102)

```
    // session cookie params
$cookieParams = array(
    'lifetime' => $cookie->getLifetime(),
    'path'     => $cookie->getPath()//,
    //'domain'   => $cookie->getConfigDomain(),
    //'secure'   => $cookie->isSecure(),
    //'httponly' => $cookie->getHttponly()
);

//if (!$cookieParams['httponly']) {
//    unset($cookieParams['httponly']);
//    if (!$cookieParams['secure']) {
//        unset($cookieParams['secure']);
//        if (!$cookieParams['domain']) {
//            unset($cookieParams['domain']);
//        }
//    }
//}
```