# Magento - Can't access admin page and frontend product not showing after changing hosting server

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.9

I Can't access admin page - it get redirected to page not found and also front end product not showing and front end links not working after changing our hosting server

Comment: Have you an error output ?

Comment: no error, just page not found and also my front end product not showing but the frontend index page shows up but no product showing on it and also the links to different categories too are showing not found

Comment: check the .htaccess file is there or not ?

Comment: yes there is .htaccess file at the root folder

Comment: can you put screenshoot of your file structure

Answer (score 0):

**Possible solutions:**

1. Open your `core_config_data` table in `phpMyAdmin` and make sure you
   have changed the URLs if not than change `web/unsecure/base_url` and
   `web/secure/base_url` with your appropriate domain url (trailing slash
   necessary) like `http://www.example.com/`
2. Incorrect permissions on `var/session`, preventing session files from
   being saved. So set `0777` permissions to var folder.
3. The `cookie` domain in

   System -> Configuration -> Web -> Session Cookie Management

   doesn't match the actual site domain
4. Clear contents from var/cache, `var/session` directories after
   changing `base_urls` through ftp
5. You can refer
   [Can't log in to Magento Admin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2176195/cant-log-in-to-magento-admin)

Answer (score 0):

1. Open your `core_config_data` table in phpMyAdmin and make sure you
   have changed the URLs if not than change `web/unsecure/base_url` and
   `web/secure/base_url` with your appropriate domain url (trailing
   slash necessary) like http://www.example.com/
2. Delete `var/cache` folder
3. Delete `app/etc/local.xml` (Re-install your project).
4. If Not working yet make change in`.htaccess` file

Comment: after deleting local.xml, how do you mean (Re-install your project) at step 3. At step 4, which changes should I make to .htaccess

Comment: After delete local.xml you can resetup admin try that it may solve your issue and keep backup for roll back